# Preventing overvoltage on output

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, over-voltage-protection

I am working on a circuit to protect an output from overvoltage. As shown in the schematic below, if V3 goes higher than 3.7 V, I would like to make the output 0 V by connecting it to GND via Q7, but that transistor is always off.

What's wrong with my design, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: VE of Q2 should be more than the VB of Q2. It means VE>3.7+.7=4.4, so your circuit works fine when the input voltage exceeds 4.5Volt.

Comment: I changed V3 to >4.5 but nothing happened, I mean still OUT is equal to V3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q7 will just burn when V3 gets too high because there is nothing in your circuit that implies V3 is current limited. When ideal voltage meets silicon in a fight, the ideal voltage will win.

> *What's wrong with my design, and how can I fix it?*

However, if V3 was somehow current limited to prevent Q7 burning, there is no positive feedback in your circuit that causes Q7 to fully turn on i.e. at the moment, it will just clamp at around 4.3 to 4.5 volts.

> *I would like to make the output 0 V by connecting it to GND via Q7*

So, you need to face facts in that trying to make this work like a crowbar circuit (that's what you are trying to design) is best done using something like a thyristor (it self latches its on-state until V3 cannot supply current).

[Crowbar circuit](https://www.electronicshub.org/crowbar-circuit/): -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for good explanation, I will check the Crowbar circuit, But I'm curious as to how can I get my circuit to work.

Comment: As explained in my answer, your circuit won't work to the requirements laid out in your question @IMho <-- your circuit is basically equivalent to a 4.3 volts to 4.5 volts zener diode.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to electronic design, so what values of Q1 Trigger gate voltage and ZD1 should I use in my application?

Comment: @IMho this is a different subject to what your question is about. Your question is about why your proposed circuit doesn't work and I've explained that so, please take that on board first and note that SE is a question and answer show case and not a progressive learning experience, forum or talking shop. If you want to know how to dimension the components in a crowbar circuit you should do a little study and first in-line is the link in my answer above the crowbar circuit. Next in line is using a simulator to test that it works without creating smoke. This is how a design is performed.

Comment: I mean, for me to give you component values would require me to do a simulation and spend maybe an hour or two choosing the correct components and working things out. You will also need to figure out what V3's short-circuit current is in order to correctly choose the thyristor. I can't do that for you and, as said previously, it's beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Yes, You are right, I will try to solve the problem.